# make null cells in pandas datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this datafram :

```
grouped=pd.read_csv('grouped.csv')
```

```
print(grouped)

     Year  Week    Average          m
0    2013    24  29.000000  -0.152174
1    2013    25  22.800000       -6.2
2    2013    26  23.400000        0.6
3    2013    27  17.600000       -5.8
4    2013    28  37.700000       20.1
..    ...   ...        ...        ...
383  2020    49  49.142857   4.714286
384  2020    50  51.214286   2.071429
385  2020    51  39.642857 -11.571429
386  2020    52  45.714286   6.071429
387  2020    53  47.500000   1.785714
```

I want to convert this datafram to a datafram that every Year contains Weeks with `range(2,54)`.

I've made a dataframe with None value in this way:

```
none_df=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((418,4)),columns=grouped.columns).replace(0.0,None)
```

then I tried to put values from the main dataframe to none_df in this way:

```
range_number_list = list(range(len(grouped)))
for i in range(len(grouped.Year.unique())):
    for n in range(len(grouped[grouped['Year']==grouped.Year.unique()[i]])):
        l=(grouped[grouped['Year']==grouped.Year.unique()[i]]['Week'])[range_number_list[n]]
        il = (i*52 + l)
        none_df['Year'].iloc[il]=grouped['Year'].iloc[range_number_list[n]]
        none_df['Week'].iloc[il]=grouped['Week'].iloc[range_number_list[n]]
        none_df['Average'].iloc[il]=grouped['Average'].iloc[range_number_list[n]]
        none_df['m'].iloc[il]=grouped['m'].iloc[range_number_list[n]]
    else:
        range_number_list = range_number_list[range_number_list.index(range_number_list[n])+1:]
result_df = none_df
```

I know it's not an standard way. and I know there are some mistakes in result_df.
for example we have repeated rows.
like result_df.iloc[49] vs result_df.iloc[51]
and somewhere that I expect that they will remain None, they got value which is wrong.
like result_df.iloc[378]

I'll be appreciated you if you make this code better or build a new function from scratch.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you please add expected output, so I can understand better and maybe able to help ?

Comment: You can use the `reindex` idea.